# Making stages a separate class and making unique methods for them

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a class called MainStage that extends to the stage class of javafx.
This is part of that class.

```
public void changeScene(){

    if(onLogin)
      setScene(mainScene);
    else{
    setScene(loginScene);
    onLogin = false;
 }
}
```

I use this method inside of the MainStage class to change scenes. I call the MainStage inside of the controller for the Scene

```
public class loginSceneController{

@FXML
private Button submit;
@FXML
private TextField usernameField;
@FXML
private PasswordField passwordField;

MainStage stage = (MainStage) submit.getScene().getWindow(); //This is where the nullpointer is thrown


public void handle() {
    submit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            stage.changeScene();
            System.out.println("Stage changed sucessfully!!");
        }
    });

 }

}
```

When I try to run it, it throws this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: /C:/Users/Max/workspace/CloudCCP/target/classes/Window/LoginScene.fxml:9
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at Window.MainStage.<init>(MainStage.java:24)
at Window.Window.start(Window.java:28)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Window.loginSceneController.<init>(loginSceneController.java:30)
```

Comment: How do i fix this?

Comment: The `MainStage stage` declaration is not in any method, so it is considered a field of the class.  Which means it runs before the loginSceneController instance is created and available to other code.  Since no other code can see the object yet, all other fields (including `submit`) are still null.

Comment: VGR's comment answers the question. Can you explain to me the order java runs the programs?

Comment: Furthermore even if you move the assignment to the `initialize` method the scene would not be set since obviously you need to load the fxml before adding it to a scene. Just get the stage in the `EventHandler`. Those operations are not that expensive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MainStage stage` line needs to be moved inside your event handler.

Currently, it is a declaration which is not in any method, so it is considered a field of the class. Which means it runs before the loginSceneController instance is created and available to other code. Since no other code can see the object yet, all other fields (including submit) are still null.

Furthermore, you can’t very well access the button’s Scene if the button hasn’t been added to a Scene yet.  It’s probably safe to assume that if the user managed to trigger the submit Button’s action, the button must be in a Scene in a visible Window, so the event handler is the ideal place accessing the parent Scene and Window.

Since you asked about execution order:  Any time an object is created with `new`, the object must first run all of its initializers, in the order they appear in the code, and then the invoked constructor.  Until that happens, the object isn’t actually created and no other code can use it or refer to it,<sup>*</sup> including the FXMLLoader.  All fields are initially null, zero, or false, unless they are initialized (like `private int x = 4;`).

Until your object is fully constructed, none of the `@FXML`-annotated fields will be non-null.

---

<sup>* Technically, it is possible for a constructor to “leak” a reference to the new object before the constructor is complete, but it’s considered bad practice to do so.</sup>